# subquery returned more than 1 value table join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a course project (something like a program for the hotel manager) and I need a little help. I have tables Reservations and Rooms and I need to calculate the amount of payment after the client leaves the room (`(End_date - Start_date) * price_per_day`), but I'm having trouble getting the price_per_day from the table Rooms.

My query only works if there is one record in the Resertvation table, if there are 2 or more, I get an error "subquery returned more than 1 value" and I don’t know how to fix it (the problem is in this part of the query `SELECT price_per_day FROM Rooms AS ro JOIN Reservations AS re ON ro.room_id = re.room_id`)

I'm using visual studio 2019 + SQL Server Express LocalDB.

I will be grateful for any help or hint!

```sql
UPDATE Reservations
SET Amount_payable = (
        DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(datetime, Start_date, 104), CONVERT(datetime, End_date, 104)  * (SELECT price_per_day FROM Rooms AS ro JOIN Reservations AS re ON ro.room_id = re.room_id))
    )
WHERE Status = 'Archived'
```

Table Reservations

```
reservation_id   customer_id   room_id   start_date   end_date   status   Amount_payable
      1               3           3      12.04.2020  05.06.2020  Archived        0
      2               2           4      11.04.2020  30.05.2020   Active         0
```

Table Rooms

```
reservation_id   room_id   number_of_persons   room_type   price_per_day   
      0               1           3             Double          300  
      0               2           4             Triple          600   
      0               3           3             Studio          400
      2               4           2             Single          444
```

Comment: Hello & welcome to SO. The error message is very clear, your query `SELECT price_per_day FROM Rooms AS ro JOIN Reservations AS re ON ro.room_id = re.room_id` returns more than 1 row, and that question is posted many times here, you should search for the issue before posting.

Comment: there's no reason to have a join in your subquery.

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to you?  You only have one subquery, so it's pretty obvious which piece of code is causing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need slightly different approach to resolve the issue.

try the following:

```
UPDATE re
  SET 
      Amount_payable = (DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(DATETIME, Start_date, 104), CONVERT(DATETIME, End_date, 104)) * price_per_day)
FROM Reservations re
     JOIN Rooms AS ro ON ro.room_id = re.room_id
WHERE STATUS = 'Archived';
```

Comment: @Дмитрий glad that helped.Thanks!